# Passing text from one page to the next using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

This is the job reference number I want to send to my form job reference textbox:

```
<p><span id="job" value="90192"><strong>Reference Number: 90192</strong></span></p>
//when this link will be clicked it will redirect to apply.html with job value stored in session.
<a href="Apply.html" class="button-apply" id="apply3">Apply Here</a>

<p><span id="job2" value="90192"><strong>Reference Number:90192</strong></span></p>
//when this link will be clicked it will redirect to apply.html with job value stored in session.
<a href="Apply.html" class="button-apply" id="apply2">Apply Here</a>
```

JavaScript file of `jobs.js`:

```
"use strict"

function storedata() {
  var job = document.getElementById("job").value;
  var job2 = document.getElementById("job2").value;
  var job3 = document.getElementById("job3").value;
  sessionStorage.job = job;
  sessionStorage.job2 = job2;
  sessionStorage.job3 = job3;
}

function init() {
  var apply = document.getElementById("apply");
  var apply2 = document.getElementById("apply2");
  var apply3 = document.getElementById("apply3");
  apply.onclick = storedata;
  apply2.onclick = storedata;
  apply3.onclick = storedata;
}

window.onload = init;
```

Here I want to store my job reference number which is from `apply.html`:

```
<label for="Job">Job Reference Number</label>
<input type="text" name="Student ID" id="Job" norequired="norequired" pattern="\d{5}" />
<br />
<br />
```

And this is my JavaScript function for getting the `sessionStorage` in `apply.js`:

```
function retrievedata() {
  document.getElementById("Job").value = sessionStorage.Job = Job;
}
```

The issue is that when click on apply link from jobs.html it will redirect to apply.htm where the job reference number will be stored but it is not happening

Comment: what is the issue in this ??

Comment: Issue is that when click on apply link from jobs.html it will rederect to apply.htm where the job refrence number will be stored but it is not happening

Comment: Do you really want to store all the values on click and not just the one you click?

Comment: No i want to store the value on one click

Comment: You are storing ALL the values on one click

Comment: okay then how can store the value on one click

Answer (score 1):

Do like this

store data

```
 sessionStorage.setItem("job", "xyz");
```

retrive

```
if (sessionStorage.job)
   document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = sessionStorage.getItem("job");
```

Check this also : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage

Comment: but i am doing like i have give the jobs description number in paragrapgh, so by using that id i wanna store and retreive,

Comment: @ParasSharma - rather than doing this sessionStorage.job  ..try this  sessionStorage.setItem("job", job);...and also check document.getElementById("job").value returning value

Answer (score 0):

Problem is how you are referencing value. There is no value property for non inputs.

```js
var el = document.getElementById("t");
console.log("value: ", t.value);  //nope
console.log("getAttribute: ", t.getAttribute("value")) //right
console.log("dataset: ", t.dataset.value) // how most would do it
```

```html
<span id="t" value="1" data-value="123"></span>
```

Event better use data-value since that is a valid attribute.

And session storage keys are case sensitive `sessionStorage.Job` is not the same as `sessionStorage.job` And this line is wrong.

```
document.getElementById("Job").value = sessionStorage.Job = Job;
```

You are storing the variable Job into sessionStorage.Job which is storing Job into the value. It should just be

```
document.getElementById("Job").value = sessionStorage.job
```

And after that, you have to figure out what item you clicked.

Comment: You do not see that you would replace `.value` with `.getAttribute("value")`?

Comment: Well the demo works so.... You have other issues like the fact you are reading `Job` when it is stored in `job`. Did you fix that?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are using anchor tag href to navigate to the apply.html and hence before your method triggering on click gets executed it's going to the apply.html.

```
<a href='apply.html'>Button</a>
```

Use something like this

```
<a id='navigateToApplyPage'>Button</a>
```

In the JS:

```
$('#navigateToApplyPage').on('click',function(){
    // set sessionstorage //sessionStorage.setItem....
    // navigate to the required page // window.location.href = .....
})
```